# Passing Variables Between Scripts in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a simple question, with maybe not so simple of an answer. I want to be able to set a variable in one script and pass that value and variable to another script. Without passing it through the url, and having the ability to pass an array.

So I have index.php in there I have a variable

```
<?php
$myvariable = '';
<form action=editRecord.php>
do some form actions here and submit moving to editRecord.php
</form>
?>
```

Now in editRecord.php

```
<?php
header('Location: go back to index.php);
run functions and edit the Mysql DB
//Ok now here is where I want to assign a value to $myvariable and pass it back to index.php
?>
```

Is this possible? I am sorry for the amateurish question, but I am very green when it comes to php.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you use sessions?

Answer (score 1):

you can set it in the `$_SESSION` variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["myVar"] = "blabla";
....
```

Of course you can store an `array()` in this variable too.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass that information in the querystring. Then you can access it via `$_GET`. If it doesn't exist, just set the value to an empty string or whatever default value you want it to have.

```
// editRecord.php
<?php
// do db dtuff
header('Location: index.php?myvariable=somevalue');
?>

// index.php
<?php
$myvariable = (isset($_GET['myvariable'])) ? $_GET['myvariable'] : '';
<form action="editRecord.php" >

</form>
?>
```

You can also use session variables:

```
// editRecord.php
<?php
session_start();
// do db stuff
$_SESSION['myvariable'] = 'somevalue';
header('Location: index.php');
?>

// index.php
<?php
session_start();
$myvariable = (isset($_SESSION['myvariable'])) ? $_SESSION['myvariable'] : '';
<form action="editRecord.php" >

</form>
?>
```

Comment: ok, The `$_SESSION[]` seems to be good. I have already started a session for the users to login, so presumably I wouldn't need to start another one right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions, POST data, GET data, cookies and database data.